# Freshman calculus - Stokes's theorem proof

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, education, stokes-theorem

Many calculus text books and courses do not introduce 
full proof of Stokes's theorem because of differential forms 
and topological concepts. There are only **restrict proofs**
(for example, **simple region**, **$C^2$-parametrization of boundaries of surfaces**).

Is there any complete proof for Stokes's theorem in $\rm R^3$
without using differential forms and topological concepts?

If it is possible, I want to teach the complete proof in TA-course.

Comment: @Normal/ Thank you. I'll edit my tags.

Comment: Perhaps you should specify the exact form of Stokes's theorem you are interested in proving.

Comment: The preparation text for physics use something like  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem#Underlying_principle combined with the curl defined as limit of a line integral (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_%28mathematics%29#Definition) taking the role of the inner loops and the line integral taking the role of the outer loop.

Comment: You might take a look at these notes (in German), starting with p. 299 (scroll down):  https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Analysis_14.pdf

Comment: I would like to see this too, but I think even just defining a surface with boundary precisely is difficult at the freshman calculus level. And I think you'd have to introduce partitions of unity to define a surface integral precisely, which is another difficult step. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Chappers/ The following form was that I wanted.                                                        $\int_{S} curlF \bullet d \sigma = \oint_{\partial S} F \bullet dr $

Comment: @ChristianBlatter/ Thank you. But, I was too sad because i don't know German language. ;)

Comment: @littleO See the proof I added below.  The reduction to Green's theorem is very easy if you use triangle meshes and the invariance of both integrals under rotation (due to the identity curl(RF) = R curl(F) for rotation matrix R).  The technique of using a linear transformation from unit triangle to general triangle and the change of variables formula could be generalized to prove the divergence theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\trans}[1]{#1^{\textrm{T}}}$

Stokes' theorem states
$$
  \int\limits_S (\nabla \times \mathbf{F})\cdot \mathbf{n} \,dS =
  \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\gamma}'(t) \,dt \tag{1}\label{ref1}
$$
where $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$
vector field, $S$ is a piecewise smooth surface in $\mathbb{R}^3,$
$\gamma$ is a piecewise smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ and 
$\mathbf{n}$ is the unit surface normal of $S.$  Proving \eqref{ref1}
with $S$ an arbitrary triangle and $\gamma$ the boundary of the triangle
is sufficient.
Consider a triangle mesh $\mathcal{M}$ with manifold topology and 
a single boundary curve and a triangle 
$\mathcal{T}$ sharing one or more edges with $\mathcal{M}.$  The 
surface integral over $\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{T}$ is the sum of the 
surface integral over $\mathcal{M}$ and the surface integral over
$\mathcal{T}.$
The boundary integral over $\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{T}$ is the 
boundary integral
over $\mathcal{M}$ plus the boundary integral over $\mathcal{T}$ minus
the sum of the contributions from shared edges.  But the sum of the 
contributions from the shared edges is zero.  So by induction, the 
proof for a single triangle proves the theorem for any triangle mesh
with manifold topology and a single closed boundary curve.
This also proves the theorem for any piecewise smooth surface with a 
single closed boundary curve because every such surface is the limit
of a sequence of triangle meshes with manifold topology and a single
closed boundary curve.

Both integrals in Stokes' theorem are invariant under rotation or translation
of the surface and the vector field.  So we can prove Stokes' theorem for an 
arbitrary triangle in the $xy$ plane with a vertex at the origin
and the proof will be valid for any triangle in three-dimensional space.

Let $P_0=(0,0),$ $P_1=(1,0),$ and $P_2=(0,1)$ be the vertices of the 
unit trangle $T_{\text{unit}}.$  Let $M$ be an invertible 
$2\times 2$
matrix with 
positive determinant
(so that it doesn't reflect vectors).  $M$ maps unit triangle
vertices $P_1$ and $P_2$ to its columns.  Define $T$ to be 
the triangle obtained by applying $M$ to $T_{\text{unit}}.$
The unit surface normal of $T$ is $(0,0,1),$ so 
$(\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\cdot \mathbf{n} = F^2_1 - F^1_2$
(where subscripts of $F$ denote derivative indices and superscripts
denote coordinate indices, with indices starting at 1).  The first
fundamental form on $T$ is the identity matrix, so the surface integral
is simply an area integral:
$$
  I_S = \int\limits_T (\nabla\times\mathbf{F})\cdot \mathbf{n} \,dS =
  \iint\limits_T F^2_1 - F^1_2 \,dA. \tag{2}\label{ref2}
$$
So the problem has been reduced to Green's theorem on the triangle $T,$ which we will now prove.

Applying the change of variables formula to \eqref{ref2} yields
$$
  I_S = |\det M|\iint\limits_{T_{\text{unit}}} (F^2_1\circ M)(u,v) -
    (F^1_2\circ M)(u,v) \,dA \tag{3}\label{ref3}
$$
where $u$ and $v$ are coordinates in the unit triangle.

The boundary integral is
$$
  \begin{align}
  I_B &= \sum_{i=0}^2 \int_0^1 \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{Q}_i + (\mathbf{Q}_{i+1}-\mathbf{Q}_i)t) \cdot (\mathbf{Q}_{i+1} - \mathbf{Q}_i) \,dt \tag{4}\label{ref4} \\
      &= \sum_{i=0}^2 \int_0^1 \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{P}_i + (\mathbf{P}_{i+1}-\mathbf{P}_i)t) \cdot M(\mathbf{P}_{i+1} - \mathbf{P}_i) \,dt \nonumber
  \end{align}
$$
where $G = F\circ M.$

To turn the double integral \eqref{ref3} into a single integral, two
integration rules based on the chain rule for vector fields are 
needed:
$$
  \begin{align}
  &\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-v} (g_1\circ M)(u,v) M_{11} + (g_2\circ M)(u,v) M_{21} \,du\,dv \tag{5}\label{ref5} \\
  &\qquad =\int_0^1 (g\circ M)(1-v,v) - (g\circ M)(0,v) \,dv = I_1 \nonumber
  \end{align}
$$
and
$$
  \begin{align}
  &\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-u} (g_1\circ M)(u,v)M_{12} + (g_2\circ M)(u,v)M_{22} \,dv\,du \tag{6}\label{ref6} \\
  &\qquad =\int_0^1 (g\circ M)(u,1-u) - (g\circ M)(u,0) \,du = I_2 \nonumber
  \end{align}
$$
where $g$ is an arbitrary two-dimensional scalar field.  If we define
the two unknowns $x$ and $y$ as
$$
  \begin{align}
  x &= \iint\limits_{T_{\text{unit}}} (g_1\circ M) \,dA \tag{7}\label{ref7} \\
  y &= \iint\limits_{T_{\text{unit}}} (g_2\circ M) \,dA \nonumber
  \end{align}
$$
then rules \eqref{ref5} and \eqref{ref6} can be used to form the system
of two equations in the two unknowns $x$ and $y$
$$
  \trans{M}\binom{x}{y} = \binom{I_1}{I_2}.
$$
In other words,
$$
  \binom{x}{y} = \frac{1}{\det M}\binom{M_{22}I_1 - M_{21}I_2}{-M_{12}I_1 + M_{11}I_2}.
$$

Substituting these values of $x$ and $y$ for the integrals in \eqref{ref3}
yields
$$
  \begin{align}
  I_S &= M_{22} \int_0^1 G^2(1-t,t) - G^2(0,t) \,dt \tag{8}\label{ref8} \\
      &\qquad -M_{21}\int_0^1 G^2(t,1-t) - G^2(t,0) \,dt \nonumber\\
      &\qquad +M_{12}\int_0^1 G^1(1-t,t) - G^1(0,t) \,dt \nonumber\\
      &\qquad -M_{11}\int_0^1 G^1(t,1-t) - G^1(t,0) \,dt \nonumber
  \end{align}
$$
From now on, we will use the arguments $(0,1-t)$ interchangeably
with $(0,t)$ and $(1-t,t)$ with $(t,1-t),$ because a simple change 
of variables shows that these pairs
of argument values yield the same definite integral values.
Combining terms in the integrand of \eqref{ref8} yields
$$
  \begin{align}
  \text{Integrand}(I_S) &= (M_{22} - M_{21}) G^2(1-t,t) + (M_{12} - M_{11}) G^1(1-t,t) \tag{9}\label{ref9} \\
  &\qquad -M_{22} G^2(0,t) + M_{21}G^2(t,0) \nonumber \\
  &\qquad -M_{12} G^1(0,t) + M_{11} G^1(t,0). \nonumber
  \end{align}
$$

Expanding the integrand of the boundary integral \eqref{ref4} yields
$$
  \begin{align}
  \text{Integrand}(I_B) &= \mathbf{G}(t,0) \cdot M\binom{1}{0} \tag{10}\label{ref10}\\
  &\qquad + \mathbf{G}(1-t,t) \cdot M\binom{-1}{1} \nonumber\\
  &\qquad + \mathbf{G}(0,t) \cdot M\binom{0}{-1} \nonumber\\
  &= G^1(t,0)M_{11} + G^2(t,0) M_{21} \nonumber\\
  &\qquad + G^1(1-t,t)(-M_{11} + M_{12}) + G^2(1-t,t)(-M_{21} + M_{22}) \nonumber \\
  &\qquad + G^1(0,t)(-M_{12}) + G^2(0,t)(-M_{22}). \nonumber
  \end{align}
$$
Comparing \eqref{ref9} and \eqref{ref10} shows that $I_S = I_B.$